Array cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
I am having trouble with a CoreData fetchRequest:
I am building an app that uses the BLE protocol to connect the iPhone with peripheral devices. The goal is to display saved peripheral devices and newly discovered devices in a View called DeviceListView.
DeviceListView is set up with two Lists, one for new devices, which pulls the newly discovered peripherals from a BLECentralManager file, and one for the saved peripherals which uses an instance of CoreDataController to fetch the devices saved in CoreData. The devices we’ve connected to are saved in Core Data (entity named: “Device”). The issue happens in my CoreDataController file:
import Foundation
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

class CoreDataController: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = CoreDataController()
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    var fetchedDevices: FetchedResults<Device> // Property to hold fetched devices

    init() {
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Device")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to load the data \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        // Create a fetch request for Device entities
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Device> = Device.fetchRequest()
        // Optionally, add sort descriptors if needed
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        fetchedDevices = FetchedResults<Device>(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: persistentContainer.viewContext)
    }

    func newDevice(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, name: String, serialNumber: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let device = Device(context: context)
        device.setValue(latitude, forKey: "latitude")
        device.setValue(longitude, forKey: "longitude")
        device.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
        device.setValue(serialNumber, forKey: "serialNumber")
        save(context: context)
    }

    func save(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Handle errors here
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}

The line: fetchedDevices = FetchedResults<Device>(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: persistentContainer.viewContext) keeps throwing the error 'FetchedResults<Device>' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers.
I am not sure what the error means as far as "no accessible initializers". I think I have provided everything that is needed. My guess is there is something in the syntax I have overlooked. It seems a lot of the questions on here regarding "no accessible initializers" deal more with UIKit, which I am not familiar with. I have tried to figure out the source of this issue, but I have no clue. Can anyone help me see something that I’m missing?

Why do you even want a property of type FetchedResults, isn’t that only to be used together with the property wrapper @FetchRequest in a view?  I am not sure what the property should be used for but could it be that it should be declared as var fetchedDevices: [Device]?

I was thinking along the same lines as  var fetchedDevices: [Device].  var fetchedDevices is supposed to act as a container that gets iterated over in the ForEach loop in DeviceListView:
Section(header: Text("Saved Devices")) {
 ForEach($coreDataController.fetchedDevices) { device in
SavedPeripheralRow(device: device)
This is my first project using Core Data and BLE, so there’s definitely a lot of information that I am struggling to grasp.

There is zero reason to have a Binding for CoreData objects in that ForEach. Just use the SwiftUI property wrappers for the list. You are overcomplicating something very simple.

I made the changes suggested. The issue remains. I'm confused by what "no accessible initializers" means. According to this post https://forums.swift.org/t/filedocumentwriteconfiguration-cannot-be-constructed-because-it-has-no-accessible-initializers/66695 there might be some private or internal initializers I don't know about. Is there a way of finding those out? Or should I just go a different route to fetching data that is more clear?

Note, you declare class CoreDataController: ObservableObject but you are not using @Published ... for anything, that is, it does not observe anything.

It means that what you are doing can’t be done. Change the word FetchedResults with the word Array

This is a link to the old guide, the grammar is outdated but it will give you the basic guide https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH6-SW1 I still think you should just use SwiftUI property wrappers

The solution ended up being what @JoakimDanielson commented. I ended up moving all of the data fetching to the view where I wanted all my data to be displayed and it the error went away. Thank you!
